# jquery not getting class name of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code but for some reason jQuery does not pick the elements class name, I understand that if the element has more than one class calling `.attr('class')` won't return them but the `.hasClass('class-name')` should be able to identify if the element has the class name.

My problem is that jquery returns class name as undefined(I got this from the line commented.).
How can I make the all other div children of the `#parent`, that do not have class `the-one` to have a yellow background.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var j = $('#parent> div').size();
  for(var i =0;i<j;i++)
    {
      //alert($('#parent> div').children().eq(i).attr('class')); 
      if(!$('#parent> div').children().eq(i).hasClass('the-one'))
        {
          $('#parent> div').children().eq(i).css('background','yellow')
        }
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
  <div class = "one the-one">one</div>
  <div class = "two">two</div>
  <div class = "three">Three</div>
  <div class = "four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *" I understand that if the element has more than one class calling .attr('class') won't return them"* - That is incorrect. `attr('class')` will return the class attribute, which contains a single string containing all the class names, separated with a space.

Comment: You alread have children selector `>` don't use .children();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `children()` call is redundant as none of the `div` elements have any child elements. Remove that and the code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var j = $('#parent> div').size();
  for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    //alert($('#parent> div').eq(i).attr('class')); 
    if (!$('#parent> div').eq(i).hasClass('the-one')) {
      $('#parent> div').eq(i).css('background', 'yellow')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="one the-one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Also note that you can tidy the logic in your JS using `each()` with the `this` keyword to reference the element in the loop:

```
$('#parent > div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('the-one'))
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow')
});
```

Comment: It may also be a good idea to store the result of selection in something like `var $divs = $("#parent > div")`, and then reuse it, instead of querying every time.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks, was just writing an edit to offer an improved version using `each` on a single selector.

Comment: Thanks, especially on the suggestion on using each().

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `$('#parent> div')` returns the `div` children of `#parent`  so calling `children()` again does not return any elements.

You can use a simple jQuery selector instead of a loop like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent> div:not(.the-one)').css('background', 'yellow')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="one the-one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

---

But you can just use css for this, no need to use jQuery

```css
#parent> div:not(.the-one) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="one the-one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a simpler method?:

```
$("#parent > div").not(".the-one").css("background", "yellow");
```

[More info about jQuery's `.not` method...](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: reason for not using css :not it is not compatible with ie<9, but the above method is great.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#parent > div').each(function(){
   var classtheone = $(this).hasClass('the-one');
   if(!classtheone){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')
     }
   
   
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
  <div class = "one the-one">one</div>
  <div class = "two">two</div>
  <div class = "three">Three</div>
  <div class = "four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Try this way

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#parent div").each(function(){ 
var me=$(this); 
if(me.hasClass("the-one")) { me.css({"background-color" : "yellow"}); } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As written already in other answers, your `children()` call is the problem, I suggest using the following solution with `each()` as it is simpler

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#parent div').each(function( i ) {
   if ( !$(this).hasClass('the-one')) {
      $(this).css('background','yellow');
   }
 });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
  <div class = "one the-one">one</div>
  <div class = "two">two</div>
  <div class = "three">Three</div>
  <div class = "four">Four</div>
</div>
```